# MQL4: How to input limit orders into MT4 during non-trading hours (i.e. wkend)?

Tags: mql4, mt4

I am pretty new to MQL4 programming. I realised that MT4 does not allow you to input orders into the system during non-trading hours. Is there any way that I can do it? I am thinking if I can save all the limit orders in an array and fire the orders when trading resumes come Monday. If this is possible, can I have some guidance on how to do it pls. Any help is appreciated.
Thks v much.

cheers,
John

Comment: you cannot put limit orders if market is closed. and it is unclear why you decided to put them on weekend. Let your robot work onTick(), in such case with a new tick arriving, it will decide that market is probably open and send the limit orders

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thks for the reply. 
Does that mean that I will need to keep my com and the EA on over the wkend?
Is there a way to save the orders in an array and store the array in local drive of the computer. When market trading resumes, we pick up the orders in the array from the local drive and fire the orders using EA.
The reason why I am doing this is that I look at charts on wkend and would like to place limit orders during wkend as I may not have the time to input orders during wk days. Thks !

Comment: yes, you need an expert advisor (maybe with a GUI tools) to place your orders. GUI will listen to `OnChartEvent()`, add an order to an array and respond (e.g., drawing the orders you are going to place if they are not set within reasonable time, `OnTimer()` should help for that), and `OnTick()` to place orders from array, clearing the array (and probably removing drawings). Keep in mind that gaps are possible, so it may happen that EA cannot place a buy limit order because current price is below the entry - you need to check that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The trading is off on weekends so the broker rejects every order from the EA. You need to save them in a struct and in OnTick() function you need to check weather its a newDay and the day is either Sunday or Monday execute all the the limit orders.

```
struct orders{  
double orderPrice;  
ORDER_TYPE type;  
};  
orders[num_orders];  

void onTick()  
{  
if(iTime(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,0)!=lastDay && DayOfWeek()==0 || DayOfWeek()==1)  
     {  
      for(int i=0; i<structCount; i++)  
        {  
         //PLace Trades Here  
        }  
     }  
}
```